# Way to initialize variable by passing into a class

Tags: android, class, variables

Actually, I want to pass a **Variable type** and **Id** into a class to initialize the variable.

Like, `Button myButton=new MyClass(Button, myButtonId);`

Here **Button** is variable type, and **myButtonId** is a id from xml.

And the class (method) will return something like that `(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);`

For this  I wrote

`Button myButton=new MyClass(Button, myButtonId);`

And Android Studio Suggest me

```
private class MyClass extends Button {
        public MyClass(Object p, Button myButtonId) {
            super();
        }
    }
```

There is an error at `super();` line.

I have no idea to do more.
Any suggestion?

Comment: you can use setter and getter

Comment: what to use in  super(); as there is an error?

Comment: check constructors @ http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/Button.java#Button just pass context

Comment: *the class will return something like* - classes don't return, they encapsulate. I'm confused why you want to do this?

Comment: Actually, I mean method

Comment: It is very confusing what you are trying to do. What is the use case of this?

Comment: But I will do this for all initialization (Button, Textview....) @JawadLeWywadi

Comment: Can you post and example

Comment: what is it exactly that you want to do? what is see is you are trying to create a custom button but what you are saying is you want a function that should return a button object of the id you provide.

Comment: Are you doing all of this just to not call findviewbyid directly??

Comment: yes. The method will do this for me

Comment: In that case you don't need to extend your button. When inflating the views are all instantiated you only need a reference to them. There is no benefit at all to do what you are trying to do. Just use findViewById each time you need it. You should read on what the Inflater class does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put at least one (context) parameter in the super function
Please check the public constructors for the Button class here:
[Button public constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html#Button(android.content.Context))

**UPDATE**

You need to pass an context to your class which is extending Button, something like this:

MyClass myButton = new MyClass(getApplicationContext());

And then in your MyClass:

```
public class MyClass extends Button {
    public MyClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also an error on Button (While passing it as parameter).

Comment: But what about passing id?

Comment: Try with an attributeset as shown in the link above